# How to keep focus on window even when clicked out of the program?

Tags: python, tkinter

please could you explain me how to keep focus and keep the Tkinter window in the foreground/keep visible on screen even when i click out of the program area? I mean if i have a windows in Tkinter in the center of the screen and i click on the right side out of the program window, how to keep the Tkinter program on the screen and not get surpassed on top by the other program that i clicked, in order to keep on top the Tkinter program? Here is a basic code

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe `window.attributes('-topmost',1)` might be what you are looking for

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Yes thanks it works!! Do you know also how to keep the focus on the tkinter window? Because when i click out of the window the Tkinter window is not more in focus, i notice that the title is more faded/blurry, i tried with "window.focus_set()" right before "window.attributes('-topmost',1)" but it doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, I assume there is no way to force global focus to tkinter just using tkinter itself

Comment: You might want to read up on tkinter's support for making a "grab", which means all events are sent to the tkinter window.